# How to Convert to 24 hour format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

In the `open`and `close`statements the `time` is in a 12-hour format. The rest is in a 24- hour format. What I can't figure out is how to change the `open`and `close`to a 24 - hour format.

So what I need to do is to change the `openTime` to a 24-hour format. 
example: 9 = 21 at the moment.

Here is the code:

```js
var openTime = [{
    open: -1,
    close: -1
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 9
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 21
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 9
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 10
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 21
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 17
}]


var current = new Date();
var day = current.getDay();
var $ = window.jQuery;
var currentTime = (currentTime) = date = moment().tz("Europe/Paris");
  
  var currentTime = date.format("mm");
  
var remainTime = 0;
var closeTime = (closeTime) = (openTime[day].close) *60;
var openTime = (openTime[day].open /60);
```

Comment: There's possible 12 and 24 format mixed. How to decide which is what?

Comment: .format("HH")  HH it's 24 format

Comment: _In the openand closestatements the time is in a 12-hour format_ I don't see that. `17` is not in 12-H format. Moreover those are not statements, those are object properties

Comment: https://flaviocopes.com/momentjs/

Comment: `open:8, close:9` next is `open:8, close:21` - they're either both in 24 hour and first is only open for 1 hour or you have to guess which is which, eg `if (close<12) close += 12`

Comment: Sorry for being unclear! Above is an example. the time is calculating that 9 = 21 and 21 is 9 + 12 so the time isn't right. I am trying to change so 8 = 08:00 and 21 is actually  = 9 PM (21). 
@freedomn-m

Comment: So you want to convert *from* 24 hour to 12 hour (*"21 is actually 9"*) - then do `if (close>12) close -= 12`

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some example inputs and outputs as your question/requirements/examples/comments are currently all over the place and contradict each other.

Comment: @freedomn-m What I want is that when I am writing 21 in the close it should be 9. It is also hard since the open is 8 and I want it to be 08:00 and not 20:00 as it is now when writing 8.

Comment: "9" is not "24 hour format" and you've asked how to convert *to* 24 hour format.   Please update the question with some clear examples of input + output.